# How to add custom attributes to apache directory studio?

Tags: openldap, apacheds

I'm unableto add new custom attributes to the existing object in the Apache DS LDAP Server.

I have followed the below link and creating the schema.
http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.3.2-enabling-schema.html

The schema has been added in the apacheds but it is not showing while creating users.

Note:I'm unable to restart apacheDS. If I tried to restart the apacheds server it won't start again.

Comment: Can you provide us with more informations? What is the error causing the server not to start ? or what are the logs of the server when it starts? What did you clearly have done following the documentation? What is the LDIF schema you tried to import? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You've to restart ApacheDS after changes on the scheme were made. Without restart, no custom scheme is avaliable.

#### Linux

Use the `init.d` script:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apacheds-${version}-default stop
```

`${version}`is the installed ApacheDS version. If you're not sure about this, try this command to find out how your init-script is named:

```
ls -lh /etc/init.d  | grep apacheds
```

#### Windows

Open the services console by pressing [Ctrl] + [R] and enter `services.msc`. Search for an entry called `ApacheDS - default` and restart it by right click > restart service.

*Note that in both cases `default` is the name of your ApacheDS instance. The software can run different instances, e.g. to run a second test instance. Per default we've only one instance called `default`. Use this name, if you didn't made any custom instances.*

---

If this didn't solve your problem, please provide more information about the issue. The logs are a good point to start. Find more info about logging in ApacheDS here: http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.4-configure-logging.html